# Angular call service function as parameter

Tags: angular

I make a simple http request for data, and build a common request function to handle same operation on my components. but I get a error "Cannot read property 'http' of undefined" when I delivery service function and callback to the common function as parameters. blow is a example:

```
add(name: string): void {
    const newHero: Hero = { name } as Hero;

    //right
    // this.heroesService.addHero(newHero)
    //   .subscribe(hero => this.heroes.push(hero));

    //get error
    this.action(newHero
      , this.heroesService.addHero
      , hero => this.heroes.push(hero));
  }

  private action(request: any, requestMethod, callBack) {
    requestMethod(request).subscribe(callBack);
  }
```

Servie Code:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpParams } from '@angular/common/http';
import { HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class HeroesService {
  heroesUrl = 'api/heroes';  // URL to web api
  private handleError: HandleError;

  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient,
    httpErrorHandler: HttpErrorHandler) {
    this.handleError = httpErrorHandler.createHandleError('HeroesService');
  }

  addHero (hero: Hero): Observable<Hero> {
    return this.http.post<Hero>(this.heroesUrl, hero, httpOptions)
      .pipe(
        catchError(this.handleError('addHero', hero))
      );
  }
}
```

this error has proof at https://stackblitz.com/angular/oemgblxrqjy

Comment: Have you use httpClient in service?

Comment: Post relevant code of http

Comment: It should be like 
this.action(this.heroesService.addHero(newHero) , hero => this.heroes.push(hero));

Comment: @Abhishek yes, import httpClient from @angular/commom/http

Comment: @SameerAhmad yeah, it's useful. I modify action(method, callBack). but why? it can be work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your action have only two parameters. heroesService.addHero() registered in your service as Observable.

```
    add(name: string): void {
    const newHero: Hero = { name } as Hero;

    //right
    // this.heroesService.addHero(newHero)
    //   .subscribe(hero => this.heroes.push(hero));

    // action method has only 2 parameters.
    this.action(this.heroesService.addHero(newHero)
      , hero => this.heroes.push(hero));
   }

  private action(request: any, requestMethod, callBack) {
    requestMethod(request).subscribe(callBack);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with `#addHero`'s context of `this`.

Try using this, if you still want to use your `#action` method:

```
this.action(newHero
  , this.heroesService.addHero.bind(this.heroesService)
  , hero => this.heroes.push(hero));
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are calling

```
this.action(newHero
  , this.heroesService.addHero
  , hero => this.heroes.push(hero));
```

"this" in the this.heroesService is not pointing to the service instance. That is why it can not get this.http.

If you bind your method call with this.heroesService (service instance) then "this" points to the right instance. You can use below snippet.

```
this.action(newHero
  , this.heroesService.addHero.bind(this.heroesService)
  , hero => this.heroes.push(hero));
```